# Custom UITableViewCells swapped after UITextFields began editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I am dealing with rather strange issue with my `UITableView`.
I have 2 prototype cells in Storyboard: one of them has one `UITextField`, the other one has two `UITextFields`.
I have a class `TextFieldTableViewCell` which subclasses `UITableViewCell` and connects `IBOutlets` to these `UITextFields`. In `prepareForReuse` I am settings all the outlets including `mainLabel` and `additionalLabel` to nil.
Delegates for these `UITextFields` are connected to my `ViewController`. 
`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks like this:

```
NSString *cellReuseIdentifier;
switch (index) {
    case addressRowName:
    case addressRowEmail:
    case addressRowPhoneNumber:
        cellReuseIdentifier = singleTextFieldItemCellReuseIdentifier;
        break;

    default:
        cellReuseIdentifier = doubleTextFieldItemCellReuseIdentifier;
        break;
}

TextFieldTableViewCell *cell = (TextFieldTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier];

if(!cell) {
    cell = [[TextFieldTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier];
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

switch (index) {
    case addressRowName:
        cell.mainTextField.placeholder = BFLocalizedString(kTranslationNamePlaceholder, @"John Doe");
        break;

    case addressRowEmail:
        cell.mainTextField.placeholder = BFLocalizedString(kTranslationEmailPlaceholder, @"pete@email.com");
        cell.mainTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
        break;

    case addressRowStreetHouseNumber:
        cell.mainTextField.placeholder = BFLocalizedString(kTranslationStreetPlaceholder, @"Eternity street");
        cell.additionalTextField.placeholder = BFLocalizedString(kTranslationHouseNoPlaceholder, @"12");
        break;

    case addressRowCityPostalCode:
        cell.mainTextField.placeholder = BFLocalizedString(kTranslationCityPlaceholder, @"Sacramento");
        cell.additionalTextField.placeholder = BFLocalizedString(kTranslationPostalCodePlaceholder, @"95837");
        break;

    case addressRowPhoneNumber:
        cell.mainTextField.placeholder = BFLocalizedString(kTranslationPhoneNumberPlaceholder, @"+420 755 999 090");
        cell.mainTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

cell.mainLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", index];
cell.additionalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", index];

[inputAccessoryView addInputView:cell.mainTextField];
cell.mainTextField.inputAccessoryView = self.inputAccessoryView;

[inputAccessoryView addInputView:cell.additionalTextField];
cell.additionalTextField.inputAccessoryView = self.inputAccessoryView;

return cell;
```

One would say “no rocket science”. But here’s the thing. 
If I scroll past the whole tableView everyting is OK.
If I tap last cell the keyboard appears (I am using `TPKeyboardAvoiding`), cells scroll up and the first cell is not visible. If i scroll up everyting is OK.
BUT if I tap first cell THEN the last cell, keyboard appears, cells scroll up and the first cell is not visible. If I scroll back up, the first and second cells are swapped.

I am providing you screenshots with description to imagine the situation better (numbers in the cells are indexPath rows). I have spent last 2 days debugging this issue but cannot see why and how this happens.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I suppose it has something to do with `UITextFields` as it happens only if they are tapped to start editing. I have tried removing their delegates from my ViewController but it didn’t solve anything. Also I have tried removing inputAccessory, `TPKeyboardAvoiding` etc. but the problem stays.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are you setting the outlets to `nil` in `prepareForReuse`?  This will mean you have lost the reference to the text fields - they won't be recreated when then cell is reused.  You can clear the text field's `text` property but don't clear the outlets themselves

Comment: Thank you very much, you have solved the issue. What a stupid mistake.